# jQuery - select nth child of a parent when nth child of another parent is clicked

Tags: jquery

how can i select the nth child in a set of `<div>`'s when the nth child in a set of `<li>`'s is clicked?

HTML below

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
 ......
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="info">
...
</div>
<div class="info">
...
</div>
......
<div class="info">
...
</div>
```

for example, when the `<a>` in the 2nd `<li>` is clicked, the 2nd `<div class="info">` should get selected.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a rough idea (untested)

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  $('.info:eq('+i+')').addClass('selected');
  return false;
});​
```

I've created a quick demo to show this working: http://jsfiddle.net/Jbgkm/

Comment: I'm curious, is this code snippet still valid, it didn't work for me, but this did: $('ul li').click(function() {
  var i = $('ul li').index(this);
}

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
$("li a").click(function(){ 
    $(".info").eq($("li a").index(this)).hide();
});​
```

(sample http://jsfiddle.net/KGQDz/11/)

Comment: +1  Beat me to it... uses the best of both other answers.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, tested with your code. Will hide the clicked element. Here you have the working example with more elements http://jsfiddle.net/v2vqm/

```
$("ul li a").each(function(index){
   $(this).click(function(){
     $('.info').eq(index).hide();
   });
});
```

Explanation, you're iterating through all the existant `li a` elements available when the script is loaded. And with that iteration you pass the respective `index`, which we later use to select the correct `.info` element via the `eq(index)` method.

Please note that `hide()` is just for the demonstration.

Related Docs:

http://api.jquery.com/each/

http://api.jquery.com/eq/